# Problem to read file .txt and to transform this as a tuple's instance

Tags: opl

I have a `.txt` file i want to read it and transform it into instance so that the tuples can read it

My text file contains:

```
day 7h 20h

care amy baba

care baba bintou
```

I want to read the text file and get the following data:

```
day = <7.20>

care = [<"amy", "baba">

          <"bintou", "baba">
                ]
```

Script is as follows:

```
// Reads the content of a file and returns its content as a string

function file_to_string(files) {

    var f = new IloOplInputFile(files);

    if (f.exists) {

        //     writeln("Reading file : ", fichier );

        var s = "";

        var indent = "";

        var tab = new Array();

        while (!f.eof) {

            s = s + f.readline() + "\n";

            s = s.split(" ");

        }
        write(s);

        f.close();  // Fermeture fichier instance
    }
    else
        writeln("\nWARNING : the file ", files, " doesn't exist");
    return s;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to define the appropriate tuples and create (empty) sets of them. Then you can use the tuple set's [add](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSA5P_12.9.0/ilog.odms.ide.help/refjsopl/html/IloTupleSet.html#add) function to add new tuples to the set.
This `.mod` file

```
tuple day {
  int field1;
  int field2;
}
{day} days = {};
tuple care {
  string field1;
  string field2;
}
{care} cares = {};

execute {
  var f = new IloOplInputFile("readtuple.data");
  while (!f.eof) {
    var s = f.readline();
    var fields = s.split(" ");
    if ( fields.length < 2 )
      // empty or invalid line
      continue;
    if ( fields[0] == "day" )
      days.add(Opl.atoi(fields[1]), Opl.atoi(fields[2]));
    else if ( fields[0] == "care" )
      cares.add(fields[1], fields[2]);
    else {
      // invalid line
    }
  }
  f.close();
}

execute {
  writeln(days);
  writeln(cares);
}
```

Produces this output with your data:

```
 {<7 20>}
 {<"amy" "baba"> <"baba" "bintou">}
```